# creating social commerce site with Play! or Icefaces?or JVM based language?

Tags: e-commerce, social-networking, playframework, icefaces

i want to build a social commerce site who can manage customers and buyers can meet their need and can do transaction in that site..i want to create it using java,but i confuse about framework i want to use..

in fact i have using icefaces but,you know,not a lightweight one,but i the component is so good,..

how about play farmework,they say play! is good and fast and lightweight,but is good enough to handle large users and the security?

or maybe a jvm based language,like scala or clojure,is that good?

iam sorry,but i kind of confuse about this thing..thanks for your response and sorry for my bad english..thanks..

Comment: Play is a full stack framework.  From top to bottom.. Icefaces is an ajax framework for JSF(a pretty bad one at that).  If you were sticking with JSF and the Java EE stack then prime faces would be a good alternative.  At my company we are moving from Java EE to Play!.  The only downside is you have to do all the ajax/javascript stuff yourself since there are no ajax frameworks for it yet.  This didn't bother me because you have much more flexibility in the end.

Comment: We just got tired of JSF and how sub optimal it was for everything.  Even with the custom javavscript I can develop faster in Play because I'm not restarting Glassfish every 5 seconds because it is using 100% cpu and 100% of ram.  I'm so glad I'm not dealing with that right now.

Comment: @Drew H,thanks for your response, ithink maybe its the right choice using play!..thanks for your response..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that Play uses Java/Scala under-the-hood which are JVM based and are really capable of powering large websites. Moreover Play is very scalable/productive/fast/easy-learning-curve (which are just few of many 'unique selling points'). Just Play! ahead and don't worry at all.

Comment: thanks for your response..:D,i think i will use play! :D